# Storing faces in database by capturing images with picamera

Tags: pi-3, raspicam

I am trying to do facial recognition with the picamera and Pi 3. At the moment I am trying to get the picamera to capture 20 faces and store the images in the database.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import sqlite3
import os
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
if not os.path.exists('./dataset'):
    os.makedirs('./dataset')
c = conn.cursor()
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
uname = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
c.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('name') VALUES (?)", (uname,))
uid = c.lastrowid
sampleNum = 0
while True:
  ret, img = cap.read()
  if(ret==True):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            sampleNum = sampleNum+1
            cv2.imwrite("dataset/User."+str(uid)+"."+str(sampleNum)+".jpg",gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
        cv2.waitKey(100)
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.waitKey(1);
    if sampleNum > 20:
            break
  else:
    print "False"
    break
cap.release()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But the line `ret,img = cap.read()` returns `False`. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you loaded the v4l2 driver for the pi camera? That's necessary for OpenCV to see it. Alternatively you can capture BGR direct with the [picamera API](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#capturing-to-an-opencv-object)

Comment: code like this is redundant `if(ret==True)`  ..... use `if(ret)` instead

Comment: @Dave Jones thanks for the answer it is working now